# how to declare two email addresses as NVARCHAR in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, insert

```
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(150) = "name1@email.com; name2@email.com";
INSERT INTO mytable (email) VALUES (@email)
```

It works fine if user only has one email address; but it doesn't insert with two. I guess it might because there are two @ in the string.

How do I insert such kind of string by this DECLARE way?

I use ODBC with Node.js on a Linux pc.

Comment: What actually happens (i.e. what error do you get)?  What do you expect to happen? How is the table defined?  Do you have any triggers or constraints on the table?

Comment: I don't get any errors. I was inserting 1,500 similar rows. Only this one could not be inserted. It took me a while to locate this issue. I expect the "name1@email.com; name2@email.com" to be inserted in the email column. table is something like name email address .... No triggers or constraints I think. I just use "CREATE TABLE mytable .."

Answer (score 0):

Just found the reason.

Like Gordon Linoff points about the contraints. I created the table with a small length of NVARCHAR which is shorter than the two email addresses. That is why.

But there are no error threw with the FreeTDS drivers.